# How to get all ComboBox ListItem values in a .NET 4.8 WinForms application with UIAutomation?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, ui-automation, .net-4.8

I am hoping this is not a silly question with a very obvious solution I'm just not seeing, but with some GUI testing my functional test team is responsible for at work for a software project, I'm encountering a change in behavior with ComboBoxes while updating our GUI automation library's behavior with how we interact with GUI elements using UIAutomation. The newest development version WinForms application that our software product is using .NET 4.8. With this update, I am noticing changes with the behavior of elements.

For example, with menu bar items, in order to get the children elements of a menu selection, the item needs to be expanded before any children are visible. **Inspect** observes the same behavior. We were able to overcome this hurdle fairly easily with a slight code modification to our GUI library. I can understand to a degree why Microsoft made this change with .NET 4.8.
Searching through all descendants of a top level window can be disastrous on test time.

With comboboxes, however, it seems the behavior is slightly different. With comboboxes, there are two children when not expanded:

```
 -Combobox
   |-Text item
   |-button item
```

The ComboBox has an `ExpandCollapsePattern`. Intuition tells me that much like the menu bar items, if I expand it and then try to get a list of children, or even descendants, I should see more than 2 elements in the collection. Even with a decent delay after performing an Expand() on the `ExpandCollapsePattern` for the ComboBox and refocusing on the ComboBox (I've read that is sometimes necessary for certain children items), I still only see 2 elements, even if I'm searching for descendants.

When I look at the ComboBox when expanded with **Inspect**, I see the following:

```
 -Combobox
   |-List item
   |   |-List item
   |   |-List item
   |   |-List item
   |   |-List item
   |   |-List item
   |   |-List item
   |-Text item
   |-button item
```

The updated method for handling comboboxes with this new behavior currently looks like this:

```
public List<AutomationElement> GetComboBoxEntries(AutomationElement parentElement)
{
    List<AutomationElement> items = new List<AutomationElement>();

    try
    {
        var expandCollapsePattern = (ExpandCollapsePattern)parentElement.GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePatternIdentifiers.Pattern);
        expandCollapsePattern.Expand();

        //Slight delay
        DelayFor(1000);

        //Set focus to the combobox
        parentElement.SetFocus();

        //perform a FindAll() searching all descendants of the parentElement
        var collection = FindAllListItems(parentElement);

        //Add every element to the list
        foreach (AutomationElement element in collection)
        { items.Add(element); }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was an error performing the operation.");
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: " + e.StackTrace);
    }
    return items;
}
```

A solution I perceive, although not practical when a significant number of items is present in the ComboBox, that I foresee to fix our problem is to use keyboard/click input to iterate through every member of a ComboBox and capture the current value pattern for the element. We have had to do some dirty voodoo under the hood before, but I really don't like that kind of code. I prefer to be clean with UIA where possible. Additionally, it just seems quite tedious.

Before this .NET 4.8 change, we were able to get the child list item elements, examine the value for each one to verify nothing invalid as a part of our GUI smoke test. Now, it seems there are a lot of hoops you have to jump through just to get the end result.

Am I missing something here that is obvious? I'd prefer to keep whatever solution within the realm of UIA. Much like coming to the realization of how the behavior changed with menu bar items, I am sure there is a solution with ComboBoxes.

I'm just not seeing it. Hopefully one of you with a little more UIA expertise can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the managed UI Automation library has some issues when *walking the tree*. In a WinForms app targeting .Net Framework 4.8, you can find the List control as a child of the RootElement (e.g., `var listElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "ComboLBox"));`). If you call this right before and right after `[ExpandCollapsePattern].Expand()`, you should get it right. -- Otherwise, you can use the Win32 API (`GetComboBoxInfo()`), or change library or use `UIAComWrapper`.

Comment: BTW, when you use the `Expand()` method, you don't need a delay (or whatever that `DelayFor(1000)` is, I don't see any async/await implementation, so you're probably blocking the Thread). Check `ExpandCollapseState.PartiallyExpanded`, eventually.

Comment: I don't have the rep to mark the question as answered, but looking at the RootElement level solved the problem I was having, even if Inspect doesn't seem to show the tree structure that way. I'm curious what the logic was for putting the List control at the RootElement level in .NET 4.8. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here some suggestions.

Since you're dealing with a WinForms ComboBox, you might as well use dedicated Win32 API to get the handle of the List Control (a [NativeWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow) derived object here, so UI Automation *sees* it as a Win32 Control, not a WinForm Control).
You can use the [GetComboBoxInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo) function, passing a [COMBOBOXINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-comboboxinfo) struct and the handle of the ComboBox (returned by `[AutomationElement].Current.NativeWindowHandle`).

If the function succeeds, it returns the handle of the NativeWindow container.
You can use then generate an AutomationElement with `AutomationElement.FromHandle()`.

This will allow to retrieve the ListItems of the List Control without an [ExpandCollapsePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.expandcollapsepattern), since you access the List Control directly:

```
private AutomationElementCollection GetWinFormComboBoxListItems(AutomationElement comboBox)
{
    if (comboBox is null) return null;
    if (comboBox.Current.FrameworkId != "WinForm") {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not a WinForm Control");
    }

    var cboInfo = new COMBOBOXINFO();
    cboInfo.Init();
        
    if (GetComboBoxInfo((IntPtr)comboBox.Current.NativeWindowHandle, ref cboInfo)) {
        var listElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(cboInfo.hwndList);
        if (listElement != null) {
            var items = listElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Automation.RawViewCondition);
            return items;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**`Win32 declarations`**:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct COMBOBOXINFO {
    public int cbSize;
    public RECT rcItem;
    public RECT rcButton;
    public ComboBoxButtonState buttonState;
    public IntPtr hwndCombo;
    public IntPtr hwndEdit;
    public IntPtr hwndList;
    public void Init() => this.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<COMBOBOXINFO>();
}

internal enum ComboBoxButtonState : int {
    STATE_SYSTEM_NONE = 0,
    STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE = 0x00008000,
    STATE_SYSTEM_PRESSED = 0x00000008
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);
```

If you want to go all the way UI Automation, you can try a first time to get the child List Control from the ComboBox Element. If this fails, try again using the [RootElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.rootelement) as the Parent Element. This will retrieve the AutomationElement of the List Control *boxed* in a the NativeWindow.

This will use the `ExpandCollapsePatter` to expand the List Control, making it visible to UI Automation.
You could also create an Automation event handler, using [Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation.addautomationpropertychangedeventhandler), passing a Handler initialized with `ExpandCollapsePattern.ExpandCollapseStateProperty`.
In case you want to know when a User opens or closes the DropDownList of a ComboBox, or what has been selected.

```
private AutomationElementCollection GetComboBoxListItems(AutomationElement comboBox)
{
    if (comboBox is null) return null;
    AutomationElementCollection items = null;
    bool wasCollapsed = false;

    if (comboBox.TryGetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern, out object exp)) {
        var expPattern = exp as ExpandCollapsePattern;

        var state = expPattern.Current.ExpandCollapseState;
        if (state == ExpandCollapseState.PartiallyExpanded) {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
        if (state == ExpandCollapseState.Collapsed) {
            expPattern.Expand();
            wasCollapsed = true;
        }

        var condition = new AndCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "ComboLBox", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, comboBox.Current.ProcessId));

        AutomationElement listElement = comboBox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);
        if (listElement is null && comboBox.Current.FrameworkId == "WinForm") {
            listElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);
        }

        if (listElement != null) {
            items = listElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Automation.RawViewCondition);
        }
        if (wasCollapsed) expPattern.Collapse();
    }
    return items;
}
```